# How can you show that the absolute value of $\sin{x}$ diverges?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is it necessary to go back to the definition with epsilons or can you help me find two sub-suites that don't have the same limit?

Comment: You mean subsequences? Of which sequence? And diverges as $x$ tends to what? Mostly: please edit your post to show your attempt(s). [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).

Comment: What's fundamentally different from proving the same for $\sin x$ ?

Comment: The sequences you want are $ x _ n = n \pi $, given $ \lim _ n { \lvert \sin { ( x _ n ) } \rvert } = 0 $ and $ x _ n = n \pi + \pi / 2 $, giving $ \lim _ n { \lvert \sin { ( x _ n ) } \rvert } = 1 $.  (Well, I think that's what you want.  Or you can edit your question with more details like other people said.)